# Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am getting following error:

```
{"image": ["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]}
```

Here is my code:

**model.py**

```
class products(models.Model):
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product_updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = products
        fields = ('product_name', 'price', 'image', 'created', 'product_updated_date')
```

**views.py**

```
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addproductform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get("product_name")
            price=request.POST.get("price")
            image=form.cleaned_data['image']
            item = products(image=image, product_name=name, price=price)
            item.save()                        
            serializer = ProductSerializer(data=form.cleaned_data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
            return redirect('/task1') 
        return JsonResponse({'error': serializer.errors})
    else:
        form = Addproductform()
    return render_to_response("add-product.html", {'form':form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class Addproductform(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = "error"
    product_name=forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg", "placeholder":'Product name'}))
    price = forms.CharField(max_length=250,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg","placeholder":'Price'}))
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

**page1.html**

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div><label>Product Name</label></div><br>
    <div>{{form.product_name}}</div>
    <div style="color:red">{{form.product_name.errors}}</div><br>
    <div><label>Price</label></div><br>
    <div>{{form.price}}</div><br>
    <div style="color:red">{{form.price.errors}}</div>
    <div><label>Image</label></div><br>
    <div>{{form.image}}</div>
    <div style="color:red">{{form.image.errors}}</div>
    <div class="product-option-shop" style="float:right">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="add_to_cart_button">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am new to django rest-framework, I have no idea why I getting this error.
Any one can help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't have anything anything to do with DRF, that error is coming from your form which is pure Django.

Comment: Please elaborate my mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed that issue. I am saving the data two times,That's why I getting **{"image": ["Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."]}** issue.I just remove the "item.save()". working fine...

Thanks