# Why can't I add a photo in the Django admin panel: Upload a valid image error

Tags: python, django, django-models, imagefield

I'm making a Django store site and I have a product class that includes an "image" field. I am using Models.ImageField and Pillow and when adding pictures the admin panel gives an error.

Error message:

> "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Shop_element(models.Model):
    name_element = models.CharField('Название товара', max_length=100, default='')
    description_element = models.TextField('Описание товара', max_length=250, default='')
    id_element = models.IntegerField('Уникальный id,не должен повторяться', max_length=10)
    #count_element = models.

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title

    class meta():
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_Plural = 'Товары'


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d')
# description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Tried to fix it myself but failed.

Comment: Please add to your question: specific error message, settings.py part related to media files, urls.py, project folder structure. As text please, not screenshots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967661/upload-a-valid-image-the-file-you-uploaded-was-either-not-an-image-or-a-corrupt

Comment: Please use search. With the specific error message a bunch of similar questions can be easily found.